# How do I use the Activity Indicator during a long process?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Edit 2 - Ok, I figured a way to do this (not sure if this is the best way) but this way worked for me, which used what AstroCB wrote and some other things - maybe I had to do this because of the way it's all in a closure already for an UIAlert and the main thread is not the reset() or something like that, not sure - but anyway - this seems to work:

```
self.toggleBurgerMenu(self)
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "Starting over will restore all previously discarded cards and return you to the start of 'Study Phase'!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start Over", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler:  { action in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            NSLog("before calling reset")
            self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
                reset()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    NSLog("after calling reset")
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    setPlace(0, 0, "done")
                    save()
                    instructing = true
                    continuing = false

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("studyViewToStartSegue", sender: nil)
                })

            })

        })

    }))
```

[end of edit 2 - Thanks AstroCB]

Edit - I'm trying AstroCB's suggestion and it's not working so I'm wondering if that's because of something to do with code above and/or below the little bit of code I quoted the first time - so in this next block of code is his changes and more context from what I'm doing (obviously an action in a UIAlertController):

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Start Over", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler:  { action in
        NSLog("before calling reset")
        self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        reset()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // Will wait until reset() has finished
            NSLog("after calling reset")
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        })
        setPlace(0, 0, "done")
        save()
        instructing = true
        continuing = false

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("studyViewToStartSegue", sender: nil)
    }))
```

...

I have a function called "reset()" that can take a few seconds so I'd like to show the activity indicator during the time it does process. Here's my code:

```
NSLog("before calling reset")
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
reset()
NSLog("after calling reset")
self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

I'm pretty sure I have my Activity Indicator set up properly because I tested it by putting an "On" and "Off" button with start and stopAnimating() and it works fine with the buttons. And the NSLogs you see there are separated by the 3 seconds "reset()" takes - just that my Activity Indicator never shows.

I have the activity indicator setup in my storyboard with "Animating" unchecked (because if I check that it shows up from the loading of that view controller and never goes away - even though the tutorials I see say to check to enable that) and I have "Hides When Stopped" checked and "Hidden" checked. I've also tried adding .hidden = false to the startanimiating above and still didn't show up.

Comment: It will not wait your function to finish, so it shows and hides it right away

Comment: What makes the NSLog wait? How can I do that with the activity indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is running asynchronously; your app will not stop and wait for `reset()` to finish before continuing along in your code (even though that's the most intuitive way to think about it when you're actually writing the code).

Because of that, you're essentially turning indicator animation on and then immediately turning it off. To resolve that, you have to *tell the app* to wait for the function to finish before stopping the animation, which you can do with `dispatch_async`:

```
NSLog("before calling reset")
self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
reset()
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // Will wait until reset() has finished
    NSLog("after calling reset")
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
})
```

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this and having problems - maybe should show you more of code around this:

Comment: I posted how I tried to use your code - what It's doing is freezing up for the 3 seconds like normal but now I see for a split second the indicator right before it does the seque you can see I posted in my edit - it includes more context for what I'm doing - maybe it's something else I'm doing wrong in there?

Comment: @TommyDraughn That's odd; I'm glad you figured it out, though.